# ¿Cuál es la manera más sencilla de usar una variable dentro y fuera de un bloque "syncExec" (o bien, de guardar una referencia "final")?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Por ahora uso `AtomicReference` en el ejemplo (es lo primero que encontré que funciona y se lee bien), pero como uso `syncExec` y la parte fuera de su bloque no se ejecutará hasta que el mismo bloque termine, no necesito que la referencia sea atómica. Me parece que está por demás.

```
final AtomicReference<Custom> result = new AtomicReference<>();

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec( () -> {
    Custom custom = getSomeCustom();
    custom.doSomething();
    result.set(custom);
});

Custom c = result.get();
c.doSomethingElse();
```

Intenté con referencias normales pero no lo he podido hacer funcionar:

```
final Custom c;

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec( () -> {
    c= getSomeCustom();
    c.doSomething();
});

c.doSomethingElse(true);
```

Marca error: `The final local variable view cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type`, en `getSomeCustom()`.

También he intentado usar la clase `Reference` y sus implementaciones, pero no parecen ser lo que necesito (que es la manera más legible y básica preservar la referencia). ¿Alguien tiene una idea de cómo lograrlo sin usar `AtomicReference`?

Comment: ¿Por qué necesitas que sea `final`?

Comment: Para que sea utilizable tanto dentro como fuera de la lambda de `syncExec`, sin batallar con haciendo un `Runnable` que reciba y devuelva parámetros, o con `Callable`, o con `FutureTask`. Quisiera algo que fuera más simple que estas alternativas y que `AtomicReference`.

Comment: Tu pregunta sufre, según veo, del [Problema XY](http://xyproblem.info/) (enlace en inglés). Deberías editarla para tratar el problema real, es decir, quieres utilizar esa variable en una lambda.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿por qué no puedes usar `Reference`? Parece ser una solución bastante sencilla y no debería darte problemas... más aún si `AtomicReference` te está sirviendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia de edición. Respecto a `Reference`, ninguna de sus implementaciones tiene un constructor que no reciba la referencia como argumento, por lo que para usarla se debe tener el objeto listo (en mi ejemplo, esto no ocurre hasta dentro de `syncExec`)

Comment: Oops, estaba convencido de que `Reference` se podía instanciar. Voy a responderte pero me parece que mi respuesta va a ser que lo estás haciendo de la única manera que se me ocurre...

Comment: Tengo un poco de feedback de SO Inglés, lo agregaré a la pregunta.

Comment: Si lo que tienes es una respuesta, no la edites en la pregunta. Añade tu propia respuesta en su lugar.

Comment: ¿Es necesario que crees/inicialices `Custom c` en tu lambda? Sería mejor si explicases cuál es la necesidad real, porque lo que tu tienes parece más un code smell (favor de alguien traducir esta expresión al español)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Este código es concecuencia de lo que considero una mala estructura, y una mala comunicación entre la lógica del programa, los datos y la interfaz del usuario. En otras palabras, el model está regado por doquier y el controller está _adentro_ del view. Yo también creo que esto es un _code smell_, pero no hay tiempo de arreglarlo por ahora. Así que necesito hacer algo con `Custom`, que proviene del UI Thread, _después_ de que el UI Thread termine su trabajo (incindentalmente, adentro de `c.doSomethingElse` vuelve a usarse el UI Thread, así que sí, está feo).

Comment: Pues si esa es la situación, el mejor approach que he encontrado es el que usas en tu respuesta, que es utilizar un arreglo, al cual puedes cambiarle el estado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**En SO Inglés** [sugieren](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34811011/2550349) un arreglo:

```
final Custom[] customHolder = new Custom[1];

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().syncExec(() -> {
    customHolder[0] = getSomeCustom();
    customHolder[0].doSomething();
});

customHolder[0].doSomethingElse(true);
```

Lo cual me funciona bien. Dejo la pregunta por si sale una mejor respuesta.

Comment: no es la primera vez que veo algo similiar quizas esto le ayude esta en ingles pero, alomejor encuentra lo que busca http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354796/whats-the-best-way-to-get-a-return-value-out-of-an-asyncexec-in-eclipse/355090#355090 Saludos